# Does Azure Key-Vault encrypt the values before storing?

Tags: password-management, azure

We are using key-vault for storing the secrets, will it give any added advantage if we encrypt the values before storing it in key-vault?

Answer (score 1):

You don't make clear exactly how you intend using Key-Vault.

As a general guide to encryption you should always ask the question, "**Who has the keys?**"

Many storage services offer to perform encryption for you, but if the encryption is not with your keys, it's not your protection.